# Can anyone help me out? Expected expression error

Tags: c++

Here's my second or third app I'm trying to rite and I'm stuck.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string ans;
    do
    {
        string name1, name2;

        cin >> name1;
        cin >> name2;
        cout << name1.length() << endl;
        cout << name2.length() << endl;
        if (name1.length()  - name2.length()<=2 && != 0)
            {
            cout << "არის სხვაობა" << endl << "repeat?" << endl;
         cin >> ans;}
            else
            if (name1.length() - name2.length() <= 4)
            {
            cout << "დიდი სხვაობაა" << endl; cout << " repeat?" << endl; 
    cin >> ans;}
            }
            while (ans == "y"); 
    }
```

Sorry for ugly code I'm just starting out.
I'd love to hear what's the error in here :).

Comment: The problem seems in your if condition, i.e if (name1.length()  - name2.length()<=2 && != 0) .You have to provide some parameter when comparision if not 0. ==> int temp = name1.length()  - name2.length(); if (temp<=2 && temp!= 0){}

Comment: If you are typing out the same expression more than once, maintenance programmers will likely thank you for creating a variable and using that everywhere, e.g. `lengthDiff = name1.length() - name2.length()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't evaluate an expression twice like this:

```
if (name1.length() - name2.length() <= 2 && != 0)
```

Here is what you should have instead:

```
if (name1.length() - name2.length() <= 2 && name1.length() - name2.length() != 0)
```